# How to set maximum width of message bubbles in MessageKit

Tags: ios, swift, layout, chat, messagekit

I have been using MessageKit for my live chat feature for my application. One of the issues I am running into is that long messages just look very weird on the screen as the width of the bubbles doesn't seem to be restricted. I wanted to figure out a way to be able to set the maximum width of the chat bubbles so that they format more like a text conversation on the native imessage application.

Currently my messages look like this, but I would want the message below to be less wide and taller: [image]

Comment: How did you make this bubble? Show the code.

Comment: Its created in the library of MessageKit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the right/left padding for incoming/outgoing messages respectively.

The default padding is:

```
public var incomingMessagePadding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 4, bottom: 0, right: 30)
public var outgoingMessagePadding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 30, bottom: 0, right: 4)
```

And you can set the padding on the layout object in your messages view controller like this:

```
let layout = messagesCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? MessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout
layout?.setMessageIncomingMessagePadding(UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 4, bottom: 0, right: 50))
layout?.setMessageOutgoingMessagePadding(UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 60, bottom: 0, right: 4))
```

You can see more examples of layout changes in the AdvancedExampleViewController [in the MessageKit example project.](https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit/tree/master/Example)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much, I didn't think the solution would be in the padding!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the library that you are using has already a width set, but in my chat (which is customised) I have `a greater than or equal than 0 width constraint` a `a less than or equal than MAX_WIDTH constraint` a `leading constraint = 0` and a 'trailing constraint = 0' and those last two I get rid of the `leading` or `trailing` depending on if it is the sender or receiver of the message.

Comment: Is this your customized chat using MessageKt or did you make this yourself?

Comment: I did make it myself if you want the source code, let me know